# Stock Data in Excel is giving two totally different results for the same stock. Potential bug?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, stockquotes

I'm trying to get current data for UMDD and I've included a photo of the error. Cell A2 in my photo is from a copy and paste from another sheet I'm working on. As you can see as of 3:36 PM Eastern time it is saying the stock price is $169.32. This is obviously incorrect as this stock has never exceeded $34. Then on A3 I typed "ARCX:UMDD" hit the "STOCKS" Button in the data section in excel and as expected excel created a duplicate looking cell for ARCX:UMDD, however, when I request data from this cell (A3) it gives the correct information. Both A2 and A3 seemingly are referring to the same stock, however, A2 is giving wrong information. Column C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J is other data I have looked up for both A2 and A3 and as you can see sometimes they are the same, other times they are different. Not sure what is going on here as getting accurate data is crucial.

[image]

B2 has the code "=A2.Price" and B3 "=A3.Price". I'm using excels stock lookup formulas to get the data in columns B-K.

Comment: Unable to reproduce.

Comment: I would suspect that. It seems something wrong with the hidden data about A2. If I copy A2 an paste it somewhere else it shows inaccurate data. If I copy and paste A3 it shows correct data.